# Parallelize chain of Gaussian Blurs

Tags: c++, opencv, blur, gaussianblur

I have this code (revisited version of [this](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjIy6vFvoTTAhUHVRQKHXPlB7kQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fperdoch%2Fhesaff%2Fblob%2Fmaster%2Fpyramid.cpp&usg=AFQjCNFW4Ds6CVpbc5aIh478XnRyXArd4g&sig2=Yob1-5uJoqHTySjAGp6pbA&bvm=bv.151325232,d.bGs)):

```
void HessianDetector::detectOctaveKeypoints(const Mat &firstLevel, ...)
{
   vector<Mat> blurs (par.numberOfScales+3, Mat());
   blurs[1] = firstLevel;
   for (int i = 1; i < par.numberOfScales+2; i++){
       float sigma = par.sigmas[i]* sqrt(sigmaStep * sigmaStep - 1.0f);
       blurs[i+1] = gaussianBlur(blurs[i], sigma);
   }
...
```

Where:

```
Mat gaussianBlur(const Mat input, const float sigma)
{
   Mat ret(input.rows, input.cols, input.type());
   int size = (int)(2.0 * 3.0 * sigma + 1.0); if (size % 2 == 0) size++;      
   GaussianBlur(input, ret, Size(size, size), sigma, sigma, BORDER_REPLICATE);
   return ret;
}
```

So, as you can see, each `blurs[i+1]` depends on `blurs[i]`, so it cannot be parallelized. My question is: is there an equivalent way to obtain the same result but using `firstLevel` instead of `blurs[i]`? So it should so look something like:

```
for (int i = 1; i < par.numberOfScales+2; i++){
  float sigma = //something;
  blurs[i+1] = gaussianBlur(firstLevel, sigma);
}
```

Is it possible?

**[This](http://answers.opencv.org/question/10380/how-can-i-speed-up-filter2d/) answer let me think that it's possible**, but I can't understand how I can implement this:

> Convolve filters If you apply multiple filters on the same image
>   consecutively, like a gaussian blur, then a Gabor filter, you can
>   combine them together. Make all filters the same size and convolve
>   them. Then apply the result on the image. Math says the effect will be
>   identical with the previous combination

Comment: You want [lazy evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation).  This can be achieved with [expression templates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_templates).

Answer (score 0):

This is possible (you can parallelize). I had exactly the same issue, and solved it this way (see my answer to that problem, with python code).

https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/667/image-pyramid-without-decimation/55654#55654